# Syntax error in If-statement with or-expression

Tags: c++, syntax, arguments

In my code for a calculator in c++, I am getting a syntax error involving the `argc` variable in the following clause:

```
if (argc==4 || argv[3]="s"){
    result=no1 - no2;
    cout<<result<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

whereas the following code with the same structure compiles,

```
if ( a || b ){
    cout << "Line 2 - Condition is true"<< endl ;
}
```

I have tried breaking down the if-expression into two separate statements:

```
 if (argc==4)  
 {
if(argv[3]="s")
{
       result=no1 - no2;
       cout<<result<<endl;
       return 0;
 }
  }
```

But if the command, **calculator.exe 10 2 d** is executed the result is 8, which is incorrect.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Turn up your compiler warnings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple typo: `if (argc==4 || argv[3]="s")`, the second one is assignment, and will always be true. Change it to testing equality:

```
if (argc==4 || strcmp(argv[3], "s") == 0) //strcmp for c strings
                   ^^^
```

Comment: I guess should call strcmp instead of ==

Comment: It should be `strcmp(argv[3], "s") == 0` if you want to test for equality.

Comment: Actually should be 'if (argc==4 || (strcmp(argv[3], "s") == 0))'

Comment: the result is still 8, result should be return 0 bcz the **argv** is d, isn't valid.

Answer (score 1):

"argc" is of type int. but argv is pointer array which points to the each argument passed to the program and it stores those as string.
and you can't compare strings with ==. So use strcmp instead.

```
(strcpm(argv[3],"s")==0);
```